# Why is the inverse fourier transform of the fourier transform of this function equal the original function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that for function in the Schwarz space I have the realtion $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(g)=g$, i.e. the inverse Fourier transform of the Fourier transform of a function is the function. But here suppose $f$ is a function in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ where $1<p<\infty$. I know the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) is bounded for $1<p<\infty$ but I was told that $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}(\frac{ie^{-iNx}}{\pi}H(e^{iNx}f))=\frac{ie^{-iNx}}{\pi}H(e^{iNx}f)$. I dont understand this since $\frac{ie^{-iNx}}{\pi}H(e^{iNx}f) \notin S(\mathbb{R})$ no?

Comment: The Fourier inversion theorem holds for a much larger set than the Schwartz space. Usually we show it holds for $f,f'\in L^1$, then $f\in L^2$ (sending to $\hat{f}\in L^2$)  then $f\in S$ (sending to $\hat{f}\in S$) then for $f\in S'$ (sending to $\hat{f}\in S'$) the tempered distributions which are the limits of sequences of Schwartz functions in a certain topology.

Comment: I see, thank you. But can I use this to show that in my particular case the Fourier inversion theorem holds?

Comment: You need to show the Fourier inversion theorem for $f\in L^2$ to see how it works when $f$ or $\hat{f}$ is not $L^1$ (ie. many limits and convergence in norm are involved)